# Unexpected name lookup on properties

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def func(self):
        self.__dict__['func'] = 1 
        return 2

f = Foo()
print f.func
print f.func
```

It prints `2 2`. Why, the second time, does it not print `1`?

Comment: Why would you expect it to print 1 the second time?

Comment: **f.__dict__['func']** gives 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `f.func` where `f` is an instance of `Foo` and `func` is a `property` descriptor triggers

```
Foo.func.__get__(f)
```

(see [*Descriptor protocol*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol)).

`self.__dict__['func'] = 1` modifies the underlying dictionary of the `f` instance. It doesn't change the `func` attribute of the `Foo` class.

`Foo.func` takes precedence over `f.func` (*= 1*, newly created instance variable) because

> If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a data
>   descriptor, the data descriptor takes precedence.

(copied from the link above).

---

You'll have to assign something to `Foo.func` if you want to replace the property:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def func(self):
        Foo.func = 1 
        return 2

f = Foo()
print(f.func) # 2
print(f.func) # 1
```

Comment: +1 for the link. "If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a data descriptor, the data descriptor takes precedence" pretty much explains things.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211233/how-python-attribute-lookup-process-works), the attribute lookup process goes in this order:

> 1. If attrname is a special (i.e. Python-provided) attribute for objectname, return it.
> 2. Check objectname.__class__.__dict__ for attrname. If it exists and is a data-descriptor, return the descriptor result. Search all
>      bases of objectname.__class__ for the same case.
> 3. Check objectname.__dict__ for attrname, and return if found. If objectname is a class, search its bases too. If it is a class and a
>      descriptor exists in it or its bases, return the descriptor result.
> 4. Check objectname.__class__.__dict__ for attrname. If it exists and is a non-data descriptor, return the descriptor result. If it
>      exists, and is not a descriptor, just return it. If it exists and is a
>      data descriptor, we shouldn't be here because we would have returned
>      at point 2. Search all bases of objectname.__class__ for same case.
> 5. Raise AttributeError.

The property decorator adds a key-value pair to the object's class' `__dict__`, so it gets found in step 2. Names added to the object's `__dict__` are checked in step 3. So between the two, properties take precedence.