# How does Python know to call setter/getter methods with properties

Tags: python

My code:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = 5

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    value = property(get_value, set_value)

a = MyClass()
```

I get the following output:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My question: Why do I get this output? Why does Python call **MyClass.value.__set__** instead of just setting the **instance variable** to 0?

I mean the property object is a class variable and when initializing the `a`-instance I do not do anything with the class variable. Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Interesting output, I wouldn't have expected that. Just wanted to add that making `value` a private variable (replacing with `__value`) resolves the problem.

Comment: @Michael that doesn't make it private, it just name mangles it. As long as the attribute behind the property has a different name (conventionally with a *single* leading underscore, but could be something completely different) there's no recursion.

Comment: It calls `MyClass.value.__set__` because *that's how properties work*. Otherwise you'd just immediately replace the property with a value whenever you assigned to it.

Comment: I would have posted an answer here, but can't because the question is closed.  I don't think it is an exact duplicate because you are asking about the error.  What is going on is that you are introducing an infinite recursion. `__init__` contains `self.value=0` which is interpreted as `self.set_value(0)` which contains `self.value = 5` which is interpreted as `self.set_value(5)` and that method calls into itself again, and again, similarly, introducing an infinite recursion.  You need to use a different name for the state variable than the property and `_value` is usually the convention.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `value = property(get_value, set_value)` you declare a new descriptor. From now `instance.value` and `instance.value = x` will call `.get_value()` and `.set_value()`.

Comment: The reason why is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36607870/5005715