# Python attribute resolution: the ultimate flowchart

Tags: python, properties, attributes, descriptor, python-3.6

I'm looking for a complete description of Python attribute lookup. I know there have been [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211233/how-python-attribute-lookup-process-works) and there is this very nice introduction to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). But it does not cover the entire lookup for example it does not elaborate on [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup).

Ideally, there would be a flowchart starting at `x.y` and then running through all possibilites including

- is it lookup or assignment?
- is `x` a class or an object (or for example a function if that makes a difference)?
- is `x` a builtin if that's relevant?
- does `x` have a `__slots__` attribute?
- does `x` have a `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` or `__getattribute__` method?
- is `y`, the string a special attribute name
- once `y` is resolved, does it have a `__get__` attribute?

etc., etc., you get the idea.

I realise this is a lot of work, so if there are any promising submissions within 5 days from now I'm willing to offer a 250 rep bounty.

Reference version should be Python3.6 and there should be an effort made to demonstrate completeness as far as possible.

I'm sure such a flowchart would be tremendously useful for me and many others.

Comment: Dear mods. Any chance of a bit of  clarification? I fail to see how there could be "too many possible answers"; as for the length do you know for a fact that a flowchart with a handful of references would not fit "a few paragraphs"?

Comment: This blog is a good start: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup